# Intellij Community Edition: Error message

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, error-handling

If I create a Console Application in the Intellij Idea Community Edition, it will ejected the following error message:

[image]

My data:

- MacBook Pro M1
- Macos Monterey
- Intellij IDEA Community Edition
- Kotlin
- Azul 13 for Apple Silicon (arm) (Java)

Any ideas how i can fix that?

I found the solution:

- The problem was that my anti-virus program (Bitdefender) was not yet optimized for the MacOS Monterey beta. So... the program triggered errors and recognized IntelliJ as a possible danger and blocked it.

Comment: You might want to put the image inline for better readability

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am uncertain like you mean that?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the IDE logs (*Help | Show Logs in Finder*)?

Comment: I looked at the log, there are errors to be found. What should I do?

Comment: What did you do before the error appeared?

Comment: I updated my MacBook to the Macos Monterey Beta. Since then I believe that the problem occurs. But I do not know in which, associated with the update, especially what Macos Monterey has changed on the functioning of Intellij Idea.

Comment: What is the actual path to your project directory? Can you see it in Finder? Do you have write access in that dir? Also try creating a new project in a new empty directory.

Comment: Also, add the _versions_ for Intellij IDEA Community Edition and Kotlin.